# Golang operator &^ meaning?

Tags: go

- `&` is the *and* operator.
  Meaning `0111 & 0010` is `0010`.
- `^` is the *exclusive or* (XOR) operator.
  Meaning `0111 ^ 0010` is `0101`.

What do we check when we're using both `&^` in the same line? As in the definition of `Abs` in `math` package:

```
func Abs(x float64) float64 {
    return Float64frombits(Float64bits(x) &^ (1 << 63))
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've duped the question, but I hope it's clear from the other answers now that `&^ (1 << 63)` is clearing the most significant bit of `Float64bits(x)` in the last part of your question. (The top bit of a floating point number is the sign bit, so this code is interpreting the float as a uint64, clearing the sign bit, and then interpreting that bit pattern as a floating point number.)

Comment: My bad for duplicating the question, @PaulHankin. With "top bit" i assume you mean MSB?

Comment: Yes, the most significant bit, and the code clearly shows that it's the bit that you get from shifting 1 left 63 times.